Can I use Power Automate to create Entra ID security groups
Is it possible to create an Entra security group via Power Automate?
I was looking at this connector
Send an HTTP request V2
but not sure if this can only used to create Microsoft 365 groups.
Do I need a premium connector for this?
Thanks in advance

You can a create a security group with Power Automate Entra ID connector, as long as Microsoft 365 group. But you cannot create Mail-Enabled Security groups.

Known issues and limitations
The connector does not support Mail-Enabled Security groups.

This is not a premium connector, however, users allowed to use this connector must be approved by an administrator and have the user administrator role.

To use this integration, you will need access to an Microsoft Entra ID account with sufficient privileges.

Source: Microsoft Entra ID - Connectors

Yes, it is possible to create an Entra (Azure AD) security group via Power Automate using the "Send an HTTP request V2" connector. This connector allows you to make HTTP requests to Azure AD's Graph API, which is capable of creating security groups.
Here are the key steps:
API Permission: Ensure you have the required API permissions for Graph API. You will need Group.ReadWrite.All or Directory.ReadWrite.All permissions to create groups.
HTTP Request:
The endpoint you would use is:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups

In the body of the request, you'll specify the group details in JSON format, like:
{
  "displayName": "Your Group Name",
   "mailEnabled": false,
   "securityEnabled": true,
  "mailNickname": "groupnickname"
}

Connector: The "Send an HTTP request V2" connector (available through Power Automate) can be used to make this call to the Microsoft Graph API. However, this connector is premium, so a premium license would be required.
Alternatively, if you need a more straightforward solution or if you don't have premium access, you may need to explore direct integration with Azure AD using PowerShell scripts triggered from Power Automate, though this method also has complexities.
